# Refresh div with JSON data using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I know this is a duplicate question but I can't get my specific code to work.

I have a JSON file that has 2 variables in it that I want to display and update every 5 seconds on my page. It works great but as soon as I try and insert a setTimeout or setInterval the data won't display.

```
<script>   
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        (function request() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "json.account-balance.php",
                dataType: "text",
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $('#trade_pp').html(json.trade);
                    $('#ect_pp').html(json.ect);
                }             
            });              
       setTimeout(request, 5000);
         });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to show us the code that fails instead of the code that works?

Comment: you should `console.log(data)`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks. This works perfectly

```
<script>   
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function updateDiv(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "json.account-balance.php",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#trade_pp').html(data.trade);
                    $('#ect_pp').html(data.ect);
                }             
            });              
        }
        updateDiv();
        setInterval(updateDiv, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for a self executing function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    function request() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "json.account-balance.php",
            dataType: "text",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                var json = $.parseJSON(data);
                $('#trade_pp').html(json.trade);
                $('#ect_pp').html(json.ect);
            }             
        });              
    }

    setTimeout(request, 5000);
});
```

Also, your `dataType` is probably JSON - setting this will auto parse the data for you. No need for `$.parseJSON`

```
$.ajax({
        url: "json.account-balance.php",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            $('#trade_pp').html(data.trade);
            $('#ect_pp').html(data.ect);
        }             
    });
```

Comment: or keep the `setTimeout` inside the function so it repeats , and just call `request()` on page load